# App Linking in Android Apps: Can I link ONLY the home page?

Tags: android, applinks

Here's a fun question for y'all. I can't seem to find out how to link just the home page of my site to my app. I can do this on an iOS app, by simply defining "/" in my AACS file, but its Android analogue is escaping my searches. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Use `WebView` in Android.

Comment: I suppose I wasn't clear in the question itself, but I figured the "App Linking in Android Apps" would tip off that I wasn't looking for a WebView inside my app.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. I didn't search well enough initially. So, here is the problem I had and here is the solution: Within my intent filter, I had the following line:

```
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with https://site_base_url/deep -->
        <data android:scheme="https"
              android:host="@string/site_base_url"
              android:pathPrefix="/deep" />
```

I kept trying to change the `android:pathPrefix` to just `"/"` and obviously that didn't work, but I can just define a `pathPattern` as `"/"` to achieve my goal without having to worry about excluding other URI paths.

```
        <!-- Accepts URIs that are only https://site_base_url/ -->
        <data android:scheme="https"
            android:host="@string/site_base_url"
            android:pathPattern="/" />
```